# Postgresql Function for Inserting Data With Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

i tried to do create postgres sql function to insert data from parameter that given in the function.

For example There are 2 tables:
Table Customer

```
Customer
customer_id
customer_name
customer_phone
```

Table Transaction

```
seller_id
customer_name
customer_phone
price
item_name
```

My current function looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLATE FUNCTON add_transaction_detail(seller_id int, customer_id int, price int, item_name varchar)
RETURNS character varying
LANGUAGE plpsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$

DECLARE 
seller_id ALIAS FOR $1;
customer_id ALIAS FOR $2;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO transaction(seller_id, customer_name, customer_phone, item_name, price) 
SELECT seller_id, c.customer_name, c.customer_phone, item_name, price
FROM table1 t JOIN customer c ON t.customer_id=c.customer_id

END;
$function$
```

i found error in my insert code. is there any way to set the parameter into 1 table then join them ? thanks

Comment: replace `FROM SELECT` by `SELECT` in the insert statement.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A simply `language sql` function will work just as well. And `seller_id ALIAS FOR $1;` is useless as the first parameter is already named `seller_id`

Comment: @Edouard I Still fine error, it says 'table1' does not exist.

Comment: The error message is explicit. What table do you want to join : Customer and Transaction ? On which columns : Customer_id (which doesn't exist in your definition of the table Transaction ...) ? In this case : `FROM transaction AS t INNER JOIN customer AS c ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id`

Comment: i want to join the data from parameter to customer table. is it possible @Edouard

Comment: Not sure to well understand your need, but you can try this : `INSERT INTO transaction(seller_id, customer_name, customer_phone) 
SELECT seller_id, c.customer_name, c.customer_phone 
FROM customer c WHERE c.customer_id = customer_id`

Comment: so what i wanted to get is inserting the parameter data, and get some additional data from joining to my master table. i added some column to help you understand @Edouard

Comment: ok, did you test the proposed solution in my previous comment ?

Comment: Your previous solution helps. thanks